# Ask the user before closing C# WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events

I want to ask the user before closing the application.
I'm using C# .NET 4.0 WPF. I can do it in windows forms, but not in WPF.
Event is fired when the user want to close the app. Message box appears, bun no matter which button is pressed (Yes or No) the application always closes. Why? Where is the mistake?

It works, but only when the user presses the "X". When the user presses the close button with `Application.Current.Shutdown();` it is not working.

```
private void MainWindowDialog_Closing(object sender,
    System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to do that?",
        "Warning", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
    if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to insert breakpoint and debug this code

Comment: The example you posted works fine for me. Maybe the issue is in a different part of the code?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The Closing event cannot be cancelled if you call `Application.Current.Shutdown()`. Just call the `Window.Close()` method instead, which will give you a chance to veto the close operation. Once all your program's windows have closed the application will shutdown automatically.

For more information checkout the [Application Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743714.aspx#Application_Shutdown) page on MSDN.

Answer (score 9):

Just call YourMainWindow.Close() and use the Closing event as described before.

Comment: That is, don't use Application.Current.Shutdown().

Answer (score 8):

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        e.Cancel = false;
    else
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: It works, but only when user press "X". When user press button with Application.Current.Shutdown(); it is not working.

Comment: This answer is for Windows Forms. Question is for WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just ask the user whether he wants to close the application, and then call `Application.Current.Shutdown()` like this:

```
private void closeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?", "Confirm",
        MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I wanted to handle all "Closing" cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want add an Event Handler before closing use this inside your

> public partial class MainWindow : Window

```
this.Closing += new ((sender, e) => {
if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes) {
  Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
else {
  e.Cancel = true;
}
});
```