# c# shutdown application through exit menu and closing event

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to close my application from Menu having Exit option and through Window closing And for both I have added prompt message.
But If I called exit then gives prompt message two times because on `Exit_Click` event after `System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();` it goes to `ShellWindow_Closing`

```
public partial class SWindow : Window
{
    public SWindow()
    {
          this.Closing += ShellWindow_Closing;
    }

    private void ShellWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Any running migration task will be aborted.  \nAre you sure you want to exit the application ?", 
            "Exit Proventeq Migration Acclerator", 
            MessageBoxButton.YesNo, 
            MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.No)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
}

private void Exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Any running migration task will be aborted.  \nAre you sure you want to exit the application ?", "Exit Proventeq Migration Acclerator", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Format your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking for confirmation when "X" button is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367586/asking-for-confirmation-when-x-button-is-clicked)

Comment: From your exit menu handler set e.Handled = true;, then it should not call the other handler

Comment: Here is for WPF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935583/ask-user-before-closing-c-sharp-wpf-application

Comment: why dont you override `OnClosing`?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever You press `Exit` button or You close the application by `ALT + F4` or the right-up `X (cross)` will be pressed, it always come to Your app closure.

Simplier way is to handle `BtnMenuExit_Click` as App closure. Then by other behaviour - event for `Window` close to cancel based on result of message box.

```
public partial class SWindow : Window
{
    public SWindow()
    {
        this.Closing += ShellWindow_Closing;
    }

    private void ShellWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Any running migration task will be aborted.\nAre you sure you want to exit the application ?", "Exit Proventeq Migration Acclerator", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.No)
        {
           e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    private void BtnMenuExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}

//designer part
public partial class SWindow
{
    //other code
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        Button BtnMenuExit = new Button();
        BtnMenuExit.Click += new EventHandler(BtnMenuExit_Click);
        //other styles etc..
    }
    //other code
}
```

Comment: Ctrl-F4 does not closes an application, it can only close an MDI-Child form in an MDI Application. To close an application you need Alt-F4

Comment: Thanks, I miss-typed.